# QueryParam vs Path variable in REST

Tags: rest

I am writing a rest api. I am having troubles in choosing between queryParam vs path variable. My api has to get user list and it takes parameters (team name, requester, pagination params). User list is only returned if requester has access to see team members

I am using below mentioned right now. I am sure that paginationParams should use queryParam as it is doing pagination and that teamName should use path variable as I am asking for specific resource. But I am not sure about requester. Should I use path or query for requester?

`/Teams/{teamName}/Users?requestor={requester};paginationParams={paginationParams}`

other possibility is

`/Teams/{teamName}/Users/{requester};paginationParams={paginationParams}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `requestor` parameter helps to identify the users collection for given `teamName` it should be included in the path. Otherwise, if it's used to sort or filter items, then it is better to send it as query parameter.

From what you described sounds like `requestor` is just an additional filter to `users` resource and does not identify it at all hence a query parameter. The other way to look at it is asking yourself

> Does the collection of users differ based on the `requestor` or is it always the same and it's just filtered out based on access rights?

Comment: Does the collection of users differ based on the requestor or is it always the same and it's just filtered out based on access rights? No, it doesn't change if different requesters has access to same team then they will see same output and it is just used to filtering out based on access rights. I am considering this as filter but was in confusion. Thanks

Comment: That makes sense - collection is always the same and you're only filtering it out. If you think my answer helped please consider upvoting and accepting it for the future visitors

Answer (score 0):

if **requestor** is identifier of **users** then use it as param, if not then as query

Answer (score 0):

You should pass it as query param because `/Teams/{teamName}/Users/{requester}` is not a resource. The resource is what you are requesting, that is `/Teams/{teamName}/Users`.